# How to access a value stored in a session from within a feeder in Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

In my Gatling scenario, a value is stored in the session for a user.
Later in the same scenario, feed is called and passed a custom feeder.  The custom feeder needs to generate its next value using the stored value in the session.

```
val MyScenario = scenario("ScenerioName")
  .repeat(10, "repetition") {
    exitBlockOnFail {
      group("WorkflowGroupName") {
        exec(session => {
            // SETTING A VALUE INTO THE USER'S SESSION
            session.set("sessionVariable", 99)  // value that is stored changes for every run of the workflow (99 just for example purposes)
        })
        // CUSTOM FEEDER THAT GENERATES ITS NEXT VALUE USING THE SESSION VARIABLE 'sessionVariable' STORED ABOVE
        .feed(myFeeder)
        .group("RequestGroup1") {
          exec(httpPost1)
        }
      }
    }
  }

val myFeeder = Iterator.continually(Map("jsonFileValue" -> {

  // WANT TO RETRIEVE VALUE OF 'sessionVariable' STORED IN THE SESSION
  val returnValue = /* logic that generates its value based on value of 'sessionVariable' retrieved */
  returnValue

}
))

val httpPost1 = http("Request1")
  .post("http://IPAddress/service.svc")
  .headers(httpHeaders)
  .body(ELFileBody("MyJsonFile.json"))
  .check(status.is(200))
val httpHeaders = Map(
  "Content-Type" -> "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
  "X-Pod" -> ""
)
```

How can I pass this stored session value to the feeder or have the feeder retrieve this value from the session?

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.3/session/feeder/#user-dependent-data) states:

> Sometimes, you could want to filter the injected data depending on
>   some information from the Session.
>
> Feeder can’t achieve this as it’s just an Iterator, so it’s unaware of
>   the context.

If your values are independent of the tests you run, maybe a good way can be to generate a csv before you run your tests and then feed this csv to your tests.